# if prompt is empty, go back to start prompt command

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript prompt, If it's not empty it connects to server, if it's empty, or user clicks cancel, I want to return to the start propmter again. I don't want the visitor to be able to join. What should I do?

```
 var nick = prompt("Please enter your name", "")
 if (nick != "");
 {
      $.connection.chathub.server.sendnick(nick);
 }
 else
 {
     // go back to start prompter again
 }
```

Comment: use a while loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Comment: I believe you need to learn some JS basics before doing chat stuff

Comment: @user3058799 - His was actually a comment, not an answer. That comment was also correct.

Comment: @user3058799 Helping others is my greatest pleasure, and appreciation is a delightful bonus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need loop, loop does something while condition is true.

```
var nick = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
while (nick == "" || nick == null) {
  nick = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
}
$.connection.chathub.server.sendnick(nick);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48U79

Comment: you should avoid duplicating code if possible. the prompt() call could be done in just one place here if you initial nick to an empty string

Comment: When you click cancel, nick is not "" but null. I will edit solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

use a while loop
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

```
 var nick ="";
 while (nick == "");
 {
      nick = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
 }

$.connection.chathub.server.sendnick(nick);
```

Comment: @user3058799 - you can make your own fiddles, you know

Comment: @user3058799 - yup, goes unresponsive probably because of `$.connection.chathub.server.sendnick(nick);`. [Deximat's](http://jsfiddle.net/48U79/) worked for me.